# Is it possible to create indices on join table using Hibernate annotations and hbm2ddl?

Tags: hibernate, join, hibernate-annotations, hbm2ddl

I have a two entities in many-to-many association. Hibernate creates a join table for this association if hbm2ddl is activated. However, since I do not have an entity for this table, I can not apply @Index annotation. Is there a way to tell hibernate hbm2ddl to generate indices and primary key on the join table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [auxiliary database objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-database-object), but it would require you to switch from JPA annotations to a traditional `.hbm.xml` file.

Here is an example:

```
<!-- class mapping: -->
<class name="Entity1" table="Entity1">

  <!-- insert other mappings here -->

  <!-- this class's half of the many-to-many relationship: -->
  <set name="Entity2s" table="TheJoinTable">
    <key column="Entity1ID" />
    <many-to-many class="Entity2" column="Entity2ID" />
  </set>
</class>

<!-- auxiliary object: -->
<database-object>
  <create>CREATE INDEX MyIndex ON TheJoinTable(Entity1ID)</create>
</database-object>
```

Another option is to just bite the bullet and create a full-fledged entity to replace the join table.  This is in fact what I did in a similar situation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply index on a collection table annotation. E.g.:

```
    @javax.persistence.ElementCollection(fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY)
@javax.persistence.CollectionTable(
        name = "TheJoinTable",
        indexes = {
            @Index(name = "MyIndex", columnList = "Entity1ID")},
         joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "TheJoinColumn")}
)
```